# How to simplify or rewrite Cosmos Query with LIKE keyword

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to modify a query of something

> `Select * FROM c WHERE c.id IN (1234, 5678)`

to

> Select * FROM c WHERE c.id LIKE "1234-%" OR c.id LIKE "5678-%"

the reason is the search keyword is a part of larger concatenated word.I want to simplify/enhance this query .

Comment: Are you using EF, or are you accessing Cosmos directly?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirements, you can make use of [`StartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-startswith).

Something like:

```
Select * FROM c WHERE STARTSWITH(c.id, "1234-") or STARTSWITH(c.id, "5678-")
```

If you want to do a search like `%1234-%`, then you may want to consider using [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-contains).

Something like:

```
Select * FROM c WHERE Contains(c.id, "1234-") or Contains(c.id, "5678-")
```

Comment: Those two queries aren't equivalent and might return completely different results. Based on  OP's question only the second one is correct.

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ - You're absolutely correct. Based on OP's question, `STARTSWITH` is the right solution. I just wanted to present both options just in case OP wants to do a search like `%1234%`. I will update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let me rephrase..there woud around 100 item .I looking for a way to not to repeat Contains or STARTSWITH 100 times.

Comment: Aah...Then in that case will something like [`ARRAY_CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-contains) work for you?

Comment: @GauravMantri I know it. I just wanted to clarify just in case the OP could take both as equivalent.

Comment: @Deepcoder You can't. If you're searching for 100 different expressions you must write 100 different expressions.

Answer (score 1):

#### N explicit ids

Assuming you have a fixed set of explicitly known ids to look for then I wouldn't complicate the query and just pass in the array. It's efficient and most maintainable:

```
select * from c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(@Ids, c.id)
```

This will use index and would imho be the preferred option to use. Passing in 100 items is ok, though I believe there is a limit somewhere..

#### N explicit prefixes

When you don't have a full list known and have to rely on prefixes then you can use the solution from [@GauravMantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) or your own like-syntax.:

```
Select * FROM c  
WHERE STARTSWITH(c.id, "1234-") or STARTSWITH(c.id, "5678-")
```

It seems to use index regardless or having the OR clause, the downside is that you'd have to know the number of prefixes to search at compile-time. You could also support any number of prefixes by building a dynamic query in client runtime. Which is slightly dirty, but it works.

#### Any number of prefixes + don't repeat logic

You don't have to repeat the `StartsWith` logic nor be limited in how many prefixes to pass in by utilizing joins:

```
SELECT * FROM c
JOIN prefix in (select value ['1234-', '3456-', '5678-'])
where Startswith( c.id, prefix)
```

You could also pass in the prefixes by variable and have a compile-time fixed query.

**NB!** This trick will lose indexing by `starts_with` field. Usable only when other predicates or `top`-clause would limit data enough, or your RU will hit the roof.

#### Unify using Regex

You can also merge the condition into single regex condition. It may be suitable in some cases where you could unify conditions by regex classes, ex `\d` etc or combinations a la `^(1234|3456)-`.

On average case though, that's more of a hassle since in a dynamic case you'd have to build the regex on the fly + I don't think you'd get any indexing..

See: [RegexMatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-regexmatch)